# What is the Android Jetpack alternative to CursorLoader?

Tags: android, paging, image-gallery, android-jetpack

`Loaders` have been deprecated for `ViewModel` and `LiveData` and Android now has a `Paging Library` for pagination.

Most examples over web explain fetching images from web endpoints.

I want to create an image gallery in my app and want to use `Jetpack` components/framework mentioned but can't seem to find a replacement for `CursorLoader`.

Am I supposed to be using `CursorLoader` inside of `PageKeyedDataSource` instance which will be used by `PagedList` which in turn will be used by `PagedListAdapter` for `RecyclerView`?

Comment: It cannot be used now, because the context cannot be obtained